# Get sum of the values of objects in an array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a dataweave input as given below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var demo = [
    {
        "mat" : 1000,
        "seg" : "z"
    },
    {
        "mat" : 2000,
        "seg" : "b"
    },
    {
        "mat" : 3000,
        "seg" : "x"
    }
]
var count = 0
---
count
```

I need the sum of the "mat" field, the count should 6000. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var demo = [
    {
        "mat" : 1000,
        "seg" : "z"
    },
    {
        "mat" : 2000,
        "seg" : "b"
    },
    {
        "mat" : 3000,
        "seg" : "x"
    }
]
var count = sum(demo.mat)
---
count
```

Comment: I recommend using `sum(demo.*mat)` instead of `sum(demo.mat)`. Both work but can bring confusion.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia which confusion? Can you please explain, I am unaware of usage of * here

Comment: Without the *, DW is just doing a blind transformation to a collection just because the object has multiple values for that property. If the payload change and you just get one, it will return one value and not a collection and sum() will fail. For clarity, if another dev gets your code and see the *, they will know it's expecting a collection.